# how to add multiple x axes to d3 chart via data join?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create several charts at once using d3 - code is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jgilfillan/W85ut/

I have an array `bulletDataX` of these objects:

```
function BulletObject(name, actual, target, ranges, bulletWidth) {
 this.name = name;
    this.actual = actual;
    this.target = target;
    this.ranges = ranges;
    this.maxX = ranges[2];
    this.bulletWidth = bulletWidth;
    this.scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, this.maxX]).range([0, this.bulletWidth]);
    this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.scale).orient("bottom");
}
```

this is the code I am trying to get working...

```
//axes??? not working
svg.selectAll(".xaxis")
.data(bulletDataX)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("id", function(d) { return d.name; })
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return  "translate(0, " + ((bulletHeight + bulletPadding) * i + .25 * bulletHeight).toString() + ")"; })
.call(function(d, i) { return d.xAxis; });
```

I know I have to fiddle with the transform attribute a bit but I can't even get the axis to display. I think the issue is with `.call(function(d, i) { return d.xAxis; })` but I can't figure out how to get it to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` method doesn't provide you with `d, i` arguments. Instead, it:

> Invokes the specified function once, passing in the **current selection**
>   along with any optional arguments.

See the API documentation: [selection.call(function[, arguments…])](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#call)

You can try using `each` instead. It:

> Invokes the specified function for each element in the current
>   selection, passing in the **current datum d and index i**, with the `this`
>   context of the **current DOM element**.

See the API documentation: [selection.each(function)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each)

Here's a code example:

```
.each(function (d, i) {
    return d.xAxis(d3.select(this));
});
```